# iOS: test introductory offer without making offer live on App Store Connect

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, storekit

I'm looking for a way to test introductory offers for an existing App Store subscription that does not currently have an introductory offer.  Apples has [this page on testing introductory offers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/original_api_for_in-app_purchase/subscriptions_and_offers/testing_introductory_offers), but I think that means you have to [enable an introductory offer](https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/manage-subscriptions/set-up-introductory-offers-for-auto-renewable-subscriptions) on App Store Connect.   However, if you enable an introductory offer on App Store Connect for an existing subscription, users will see the offer before it can be tested.  I want to be able to test things like how it shows in the UI and how the backend should handle fields in the payload like `is_trial_period`.  Is there a way to test this that does not involve making the introductory offer live on App Store Connect, or at least not making it available to all users?